# Defining a struct::matrix object inside a class method

Tags: tcl

I have a script that uses the `struct::matrix` package. The following is **basically** the code I'm using:

```
body className::methodName {args} {
    # ...
    ::struct::matrix mat
    set CSV_file_handle [open $CSV_file_path]
    csv::read2matrix $CSV_file_handle mat , auto
    close $CSV_file_handle
    set workbook_list [mat serialize]
    # ...
}
```

And when executing the file, an error rises (omitted irrelevant info):

```
$ tclsh script.tcl

invalid command name "mat"
    while executing
"$m columns"
    (procedure "Split2matrix" line 25)
    invoked from within
"Split2matrix $alternate $m $data $sepChar $expand"
    (procedure "csv::read2matrix" line 87)
    invoked from within
"csv::read2matrix $CSV_file_handle mat , auto"
    (object "::classObject" method "::className::methodName" body line ...)
```

When the line `::struct::matrix mat` is transferred to global scope, then everything work OK.
Do you know how to make it work while the `mat` object is defined inside the method's body?

Edit:
Forgot to mention - as can be seen from the code, I'm also using the CSV package!

Comment: It could be a namespaces issue like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947460/tcl-throws-invalid-command-name-when-writing-csv-data-to-a-matrix-within-a-names

Comment: Can you make "mat" global -- `::struct::matrix ::mat` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Glenn Jackman said, it's a matter of namespace. If you call the following statements in the global scope:

```
set m [::struct::matrix mat]
puts "m is $m"               ;# ==> m is ::mat
```

However, within your class (I assume you use Itcl), then the namespace is a little different:

```
body className::methodName {args} {
    # ...
    set m [::struct::matrix mat]
    puts "m is $m"               ;# ==> m is ::className::mat
```

Instead of having to deal with namespaces, there is a different (if not better) way: use automatic naming:

```
body className::methodName {args} {
    # ...
    set mat [::struct::matrix]
    puts "mat is $mat"               ;# ==> mat is ::className::matrix1
```

From now on, you only have to deal with `$mat`, which works both within and outside of a class' scope. Of course, if you want to use `$mat` from another *method*, you need to save it as a class variable or pass from one method to another (for example, via `return` statement).